# Find the value of $f''(2).g''(2)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable functions on R+ such that $xf'(x)+ g(x)=0$ and $xg'(x)+ f(x)=0$ for all $x \in R^+ $ and $f(1)+g(1)=4$ then find the value of $f''(2).g''(2)$?

I equated value of $x$ for both given equations and then integrated to get $g^2(x)=f^2(x)+C$ but it is not leading towards $f''(2).g''(2)$. Could someone give me some hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$xf'(x)+ g(x)=0\to xf''(x)+f'(x)+g'(x)=0\quad (1)$$

$$xg'(x)+ f(x)=0\to xg''(x)+f'(x)+g'(x)=0\quad(2)$$

so $(1)-(2)$ give us

$$x(f''(x)-g''(x))=0\to f''(x)=g''(x), \text{ for $x\ne0$}.$$

and using @Salahamam's result ($f(x)+g(x)=4/x$) we get that

$$f'(x)+g'(x)=-\frac{4}{x^2}$$

and then backing to $(1)$

$$f''(x)=\frac{4}{x^3}$$

and then

$$f''(2)g''(2)=(f''(2))^2=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your citation.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: you are very welcome. I think that's the idea of MS, learn with each other.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

$$\frac {d (xf (x)+xg (x))}{dx}=$$
$$xf'(x)+g (x)+xg' (x)+f (x) =0$$

$$\implies x (f (x)+g (x))=4$$

Differentiating your first equation and replacing $ xg'(x) $ in the second, we find that $f $ satisfies
$$x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)-f (x)=0$$ 
which gives $f (x)=\frac {2}{x}=g (x) $
and
$$f''(2)g''(2)=\frac {16}{64} =1/4$$

Comment: +1. Nice idea. Just to add some minor, in order to find the result you don't need to find $f(x)$. I wrote that in my solution.